# Increase Grid position by a number, randomly split over x & y that equal that number

Tags: python, path-finding, a-star

I have created an path finding algorithm visuliser using pygame, that shows A* Vs. Dijkstra's Algorith.

the start node,end node and obstacles are all randomly positioned as such

```
def generate_num(x, y):
    return randint(x, y)
....
....
 for x in range(0, density):
        row_pos = generate_num(0, rows - 1)
        col_pos = generate_num(0, rows - 1)
        node = grid[row_pos][col_pos]
        if not start and node != end:
            start = node
            start.makeStartNode()

        elif not end and node != start:
            end = node
            end.makeEndNode()

        elif node != end and node != start:
            node.makeObstacle()
```

in order to evaluate, my algorithms I am constraining the distance between the start and end node (for small, medium and large) and thus need to make the end node eg (10,30,50) grid blocks away.

however i do not want it to be evenly spread across `grid[x][y]` i would like it to be random.

so if distance is set to 50, `grid[x][y]` could be `grid[17][33]` or `grid[10][40]` or `grid[25][25]` but will always add up to being 50 nodes away

the `makexxxNode()`function simply changed the colour of the the node to identify its type visually.

Comment: Generate one random number x and set y to 50 - x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was as simple as what @hilberts_drinking_problem stated `y = 50 - x` as x is random number.